# How to remove duplicates based upon the string's combination?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I want to compare `getA`(eg: 123) & `getB`(eg: 456) and find duplicate records.

```
P1   getA           getB 
1    000123000      456      
P2   getA           getB 
2    000123001      456
```

I tried below but it finds duplicates based on `getA` & `getB` combination:

```
Map<Object, Boolean> findDuplicates = productsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(cm -> Arrays.asList(cm.getB(),cm.getA().substring(3, cm.getCode().length() - 3)), cm -> false, (a, b) -> true));
```

Now I am trying to remove the record which has `cm.getA` value as lowest but unable to use comapartor here:

```
productsList.removeIf(cm -> cm.getA() && findDuplicates .get(Arrays.asList(cm.getB(),cm.getA().substring(3, cm.getA().length() - 3))));
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: What is `getCode()`? How does it relate to `getA()`?

Comment: @Holger Sorry i took reference from another question to to relate to my scenario..

Comment: Can you also elaborate on “which has `cm.getA` value as lowest”? Do you mean the lowest of all products with the same `Arrays.asList(cm.getB(),cm.getA().substring(3, cm.getA().length() - 3))` key?

Comment: First i want to find duplicate products based upon getA() middle digits(eg: 123) & getB ......then i want to compare duplicates from getA() & find which one which is lowest code(for Eg : 000123000 )     @Holger

Comment: I assume, if you have, e.g. `000123000`, `000123001`, `000124000`, `000124001`, you want to remove `000123000` and `000124000`, which are the lowest of their groups.

Comment: @Holger Yes i want to remove that products  and add into another list

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217964/2711488). Since both variants do already have the affected elements in a collection prior to calling `removeAll`, adding them into another list should be trivial…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Map of the duplicate key to boolean, you can use a map of duplicate key and TreeSet also. This will make it in one step. As in the TreeSet, the elements always remain sorted, you don't need to sort it in in the next step to find the minimum value.

```java
public class ProductDups {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();
        productsList.add(new Product("000123000", "456"));
        productsList.add(new Product("000123001", "456"));
        productsList.add(new Product("000124003", "567"));
        productsList.add(new Product("000124002", "567"));

        List<Product> minDuplicates = productsList.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                p -> Arrays.asList(p.getB(),
                                        p.getA().substring(3, p.getA().length() - 3)),
                                p -> {
                                    TreeSet<Product> ts = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Product::getA));
                                    ts.addAll(Arrays.asList(p));
                                    return ts;
                                },
                                (a, b) -> {
                                    a.addAll(b);
                                    return a;
                                }
                        )
                )
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
                .map(e -> e.getValue().first())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(minDuplicates);

    }
}
class Product {

    String a;
    String b;

    public Product(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "a='" + a + '\'' +
                ", b='" + b + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two steps

```
Function<Product,Object> dupKey = cm ->
    Arrays.asList(cm.getB(), cm.getA().substring(3, cm.getA().length() - 3));

Map<Object, Boolean> duplicates = productsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(dupKey, cm -> false, (a, b) -> true));

Map<Object,Product> minDuplicates = productsList.stream()
    .filter(cm -> duplicates.get(dupKey.apply(cm)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(dupKey, Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Product::getA))));

productsList.removeAll(minDuplicates.values());
```

First, it identifies the keys which have duplicates, then, it collects the minimum for each key, skipping elements not having duplicates. Finally, remove the selected values.

In principle, this can be done in one step, but then, it requires an object holding both information, whether there were duplicates for a particular key and which has minimum value of them:

```
BinaryOperator<Product> min = BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Product::getA));

Set<Product> minDuplicates = productsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(dupKey, cm -> Map.entry(false,cm),
            (a, b) -> Map.entry(true, min.apply(a.getValue(), b.getValue()))),
        m -> m.values().stream().filter(Map.Entry::getKey)
              .map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toSet())));

productsList.removeAll(minDuplicates);
```

This uses `Map.Entry` instances to hold two values of different type. For keeping the code readable, it uses Java 9’s `Map.entry(K,V)` factory method. When support for Java 8 is required, it’s recommended to create your own factory method to keep the code simple:

```
static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V> entry(K k, V v) {
    return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(k, v);
}
```

then use that method instead of `Map.entry`.

The logic stays the same as in the first variant, it maps values to `false` and the element itself and merges them to `true` and the minimum element, but now in one go. The filtering has to be done afterwards, to skip the `false` elements, then map to the minimum element and collect them into a `Set`.

Then, using `removeAll` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the string to an array list and the loop through the array list and compare it with the other array list if that is what you are trying to do.